# Hide auto generate button in a Jquery datatable base on a value of a field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I Want to hide the delete button on my Jquery datatable when the value of the field MessageSent is false. At the moment the delete button displayed on every row. I need to add the statement below but I don't know how to add it

Statement I want to add

```
  if (MessageSent = 0) {
    return '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="/MessageReport/Delete?MessageId=' + full.MessageId + '&MobileNumber=' + full.MobileNumber + '">Delete </a>';
   }
```

Jquery Datatable

```
  var schedulemessageListVM;
$(function () {
    schedulemessageListVM = {
        dt: null,
        init: function () {
            dt = $('#schedulemessage-data-table').DataTable({
                //"dom": '<"top"if>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
                "pageLength": 10,
                "serverSide": true,
                "processing": true,
                "language": {
                    processing: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span> '
                },
                "order": [[0, "desc"]],
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/MessageReport/LoadData2",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype": "json",
                },
                "columns": [
                    {
       // add the if statement here
                        "targets": [0][3],
                        "data": "MessageId", "autoWidth": true,
                        "render": function (data, type, full) {
                            return '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="/MessageReport/Delete?MessageId=' + full.MessageId + '&MobileNumber=' + full.MobileNumber + '">Delete </a>';
                        }
                    },
                    { "title": "Message Id", "data": "MessageId", "name": "MessageId", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "title": "Message Sent", "data": "MessageSent", "name": "MessageSent", "autoWidth": true }

     ],
    // initialize the datatables
    schedulemessageListVM.init();

});
```

Comment: use `full.MessageSent` ...

Comment: Worked fine Thanks David